# Error to share file: Failed to execute 'share' on 'Navigator': Must be handling a user gesture to perform a share request

Tags: javascript, share

I have this method that is called from an icon on the screen but throws the error that I mention in the title. The method calls a service that downloads a base64 document and then shares it.

In case you can think of an alternative option to not use navigator.share(), I'm using Vue.js for the frontend.
I guess the reason for this is when the call to service file stops the code execution and we do some user interaction on the browser, chrome decides this code block is not associated with to last interaction so not allowed.

```
async shareFile(file, section) {
                    let data = this.isCertificateDetail ? this.certificateData : this.policyData;

                    try {
                        NF.UI.Page.block();
                        
                        let response = await this.DocumentationDownloadApiHelper.PostDownloadDocument(DownloadDocumentData);

                        if (response?.data) {
                            var binaryString = window.atob(response.data.stream);
                            var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
                            var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
                            for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
                                var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
                                bytes[i] = ascii;
                            }
                            var blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: "application/pdf" });

                            const file = new File([blob], response.data.document_name, { type: blob.type });
                            const fileToShare = {
                                title: response.data.document_name,
                                files: [file]
                            }
                            
                            if (navigator.share) {
                                navigator.share(fileToShare);
                            } else {
                                Common.Notifications.ShowERRORMessage('Error in share');
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            this.loadDocumentationDownloadError(section);
                        }

                    } catch (e) {
                        this.loadDocumentationDownloadError(section);
                    } finally {
                        NF.UI.Page.unblock();
                    }
                },
```

Failed to share file using navigator.share()

Comment: For me, Chrome works just fine in a similar situation (XMLHttpRequest between the click and the share), but getting this error in Edge...